# Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation v was nullptr

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am working on a project for my programming class and I am getting this error "Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation v was nullptr. I am working with C++ and including Python data. The error comes up on line 32:

```
PyObject* my_result = PyObject_CallObject(my_function, NULL);
```

Here is the code up to the error:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#define NOMINMAX
#include <Windows.h>
#undef NOMINMAX
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <stream>

using namespace std;

void CallProcedure(string pName)
{
    char* procname = new char[pName.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(procname, pName.c_str());

    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject* my_module = PyImport_ImportModule("PythonCode");
    PyErr_Print();
    PyObject* my_function = PyObject_GetAttrString(my_module, procname);
    PyObject* my_result = PyObject_CallObject(my_function, NULL);
```

Comment: This is neither a C++ nor a Visual C++ problem.    It is a problem with the particular API you are using.   Try reading the documentation for that API.

Comment: Too little information given to be of much help, but a bit of advice: Check the return values.  I wouldn't be surprised if any or all of `PyImport_ImportModule`, `PyObject_GetAttrString`, and `PyObject_CallObject` return  null pointer on failure.

Comment: On a side note, you don't need to copy the `string` to a `char[]`, you can use the `string::c_str()` method to pass the `string` directly to `PyObject_GetAttrString()`, eg: `PyObject_GetAttrString(my_module, pName.c_str())`